# Making a timer in Arduino whilst checking for input

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to wait for a period of time while checking whether a button is pressed (so whether an input is HIGH or LOW).

The delay function is annoying to use for this because it cannot check whether something is happening while being delayed, so it would have to wait for 1 ms, check, wait, check, wait, check etc...

Can you help me with the coding I would need to check and pause for a set amount of time, at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can realize that with a second condition-controlled loop.
If you want to wait in each arduino main loop as an example for 20 seconds and execute in this time span further code you can do this as follows:

```
unsigned long startTime = millis();     // Number of milliseconds since the program started (unsigned long)
unsigned long intervalTime = 20000UL;   // equals 20 seconds
int buttonPin = 3;                      // used button pin

void loop()
{
    while(millis() - startTime < intervalTime){
        if(digitalRead(buttonPin)==HIGH){
           //...
        }
        else {
           //...
        }
    }

   //...
}
```